# How can I access dynamically created objects which are created out of the scope of the current function?

Tags: c++, exception, object, pointers, dynamic

I want to pass an uninitialized object pointer to some method. Within that method I'll create an instance of the object using the `new` operator (or `malloc`) and assign its address to the passed pointer. This is part of my code:

```
void test(testClass* t){
    ...
    t = new testClass();
    ...
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    testClass* t = NULL;
    test(t);
    cout<<t->getTestValue()<<endl;
    delete t;
}
```

My problem is in the `_tmain` function (after calling `test`) where I want to call the `getTestValue` method of the object pointed to by `t`. Here my program crashes and terminates with an access violation unexpected exception.

It seems an object created dynamically (using operator `new` and even `malloc`) is not usable outsie of the scope of the function `test`. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change a pointer in a function, it must be passed by reference:

```
void test(testClass*& t)
```

Otherwise, the change made inside the function is not visible on the outside.

Your original pointer doesn't get changed, remains `NULL`, and thus runs into **undefined behavior** and a crash.

Whenever you pass a parameter by value, a copy is made inside a function. So when you do `t = new testClass();`, you're actually working on a **copy** of your pointer.

Comment: I changed my test function a little & everything in now OK!
void test(testClass** t){
    ...
     * t = new testClass();
    ...
}
& in my main method:
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    testClass* t = NULL;
    test(&t);
    ...
}

Comment: @EhsanKhodarahmi why? Using a reference is simpler and cleaner. You only needed to change the signature, nothing else. Please get used to using references.

Comment: There are some (such as Google http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml) who use the convention that parameters that will be changed should be passed as pointers, and references should only be used for parameters that will not be changed (implying that parameters of a reference type should always be const).